# Subset data in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I have several time series and want to regress the dependent variable on the explanatory variables. My question is: Because of structural breaks in my series I do not want to include all the observations in my regression. How can I select the a range of observations for my regression using R?

1. 5
2. 6
3. 8
4. 20
5. 25
6. 28

For example: Suppose this is my data set. Now for my first regression I just want to use the obeservations 1 to 3 and for the second regression I want to use the observations 4 to 6. How can this be done without opening my dataset in excel and then rearrange my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ddf is your data.frame in R, ddf[1:3,] will be first 3 rows and ddf[4:6,] will be the next 3 rows.

```
> ddf
        vnum1 vint1
1   3.0234578     8
2   0.3066877     1
3   0.5863406    10
4   0.7042274     9
5  -0.3851640     8
6   1.1231421     3
7   1.8489773     5
8  -0.3630053     8
9   1.1821609     4
10 -0.5690902     9
> 
> 
> ddf[1:3,]
      vnum1 vint1
1 3.0234578     8
2 0.3066877     1
3 0.5863406    10
> 
> ddf[5:8,]
       vnum1 vint1
5 -0.3851640     8
6  1.1231421     3
7  1.8489773     5
8 -0.3630053     8
```

So you can run your regression as:

```
lm(vnum1~vint1, data=ddf[1:3,])
```

Comment: Indeed, though perhaps `lm(vnum1 ~ vint1, data=ddf, subset=1:3)` is a little clearer when it is available.

Comment: woow many thanks to both of you for your fast reply. They are very helpful! since I have not enough reputation I cannot upvote your answer...

Comment: In easier approach, IMHO, is to use a grouping variable and run the same model for each subset designated by the variable "group":
ddf<-data.frame(x=rnorm(12), y=rnorm(12), group=rep(1:3, each=4))
library(lme4)

#Fit the model once for each group designated by the variable "group"
fits <- lmList(y ~ x | group, data=ddf)
fits

#Compare the results above to:
lm(y[1:4]~x[1:4], data=ddf)
lm(y[5:8]~x[5:8], data=ddf)
lm(y[9:12]~x[9:12], data=ddf)